# Add values to one array after explode function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get all the paths from all the rows and to add them (after exploding) to one array (in order to present them as checkbox)

This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select path from audit where ind=$ind");
$exp = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    foreach ($row as $fpath)
      {
       $path = explode("/", $fpath);
       array_push($exp, $path);
      }
  }
```

My output is like that:

```
Array ( [0] => 
   Array ( [0] => [1] => my [2] => path  ) 
   [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => another [2] => one  )
```

How can i combine them to one array?

I want to get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => my [2] => path  [3] => another [4] => one  )
```

Thank you!

Comment: what you expect to have in final ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the array_merge function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Use the following lines of code:

```
$path = explode("/", $fpath);
$exp = array_merge($exp, $path);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) :

```
$result = mysql_query("select path from audit where ind=$ind");
$exp = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    foreach ($row as $fpath)
      {
       $path = explode("/", $fpath);
       $exp = array_merge($exp, $path);
      }
  }
```